# How to code INSERT Subquery correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tested each part of the SQL and it works fine.

Something is Wrong with my `WHERE` clause however.. not getting much detail setting breakpoints in VS 2012 however...

How should this be code for an `INSERT` statement with a subquery using MS SQL SERVER?

```
INSERT INTO Emails (email, insertDate) 
VALUES (@Email, @DateToday) 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Emails.email 
                  FROM Emails WHERE Emails.email = @Email);
```

Comment: Does that code even compile/run? What does a `WHERE` mean without a SELECT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Emails (email, insertDate) 
SELECT @Email, @DateToday
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Emails.email 
                  FROM Emails WHERE Emails.email = @Email);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
INSERT INTO Emails (email, insertDate) 
SELECT @Email, @DateToday
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Emails.email 
                  FROM Emails WHERE Emails.email = @Email)
```

But a **better solution** may be a unique index on the email column

Answer (score 2):

Try to use like following :

```
"INSERT INTO Emails (email, insertDate) VALUES ('@Email', '@DateToday') WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Emails.email FROM Emails WHERE Emails.email = '@Email');"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Emails (email, insertDate) 
SELECT Email, DateToday
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT Emails.email 
                  FROM Emails WHERE Emails.email = Email)
```

It will work set `email` as a **not null column** or **unique index**.